# User-Controlled Encryption in web app. How to Implement Encrypted Content Sharing Among Friends?

Tags: encryption, web-application, privacy, appsec

I'm working on idea for a project the goal is to allow a user to share their encrypted content with friends while ensuring the server and none friends maintains zero knowledge of the actual content.

Here's an example structure of a user:

```
User: {
  name: String,
  content: String (Encrypted),
  friends: List[User...]
}
```

I need help understanding the following functionalities:

User Creation and Key Pair Generation:

- How can I generate a key pair (public and private) for a user securely in Node.js?

Adding Friends and Sharing Content:

- Once users are created, how can a user add a friend and share their encrypted content with them?
- How do I derive shared keys between friends to enable encrypted content sharing?

Secure Content Update and Reading:

- How can a user securely update their encrypted content on the server?
- How do friends securely read the shared content without the server having knowledge of it?

Comment: You want to look into homomorphic encryption. Cloud providers use it to analyze files while maintaining privacy. There are open source library implementations that allow you to use homomorphic encryption in web apps. Here is more information about homomorphic encryption. https://digitalprivacy.ieee.org/publications/topics/what-is-homomorphic-encryption.

Comment: interesting will check it out, although seems a bit over my head, I figured this wouldn't be so complicated actually haha!

Comment: @FullArray homomorphic encryption seems more focused on for example site wanting to store user data encrypted, but still be able to query/aggregate the data. In my case the site doesn't want/need to query/aggregate or read the data it just stores and transmits encrypted data that other users decrypt